# C++ - what is the best library that I can use to create GUI if a textview already exists

Tags: c++, mvc

I have a 2D char array in the textView.Basically,I need to map each char to a texture and render the whole view. Given a limited time, what is the possible best library that I can use?

The header for the text view is

```
    class TextView {
    char **theMap;
    std::string race;
    int gold;
    int flr;
    int hp;
    int atk;
    int def;
    std::string action;
    std::string pendingAction;
public:
    TextView();
    void update(int x, int y, char c);

    // for the rest of the methods, notice that it takes
    // the NEW VALUE rather than the CHANGE as its parameter
    void updateGold(int newValue);
    void updateHp(int newValue);
    void updateAtk(int newValue);
    void updateDef(int newValue);
    void updateFlr(int newValue);
    void updateRace(std::string newValue);
    void updateAction(std::string newValue);

    void print(); // just print to cout, rather than give a reference to a ostream
    ~TextView();
};
```

Comment: Use `SDL`. It's one of the best availiable options. You can easily do simple graphics with it. And it also supports OpenGL graphics too if you want somethign more advanced.

Comment: Or you can use QT too